# Prove that the union of two bases in different subspaces is a basis for vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question from Finite-Dimensional Linear Algebra by Mark S. Gockenbach page 72 (Exercise 2.7.14). I hope to check my proof. Thank you.

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and suppose $S$ and $T$ are subspaces of $V$ satisfying $S \cap T = \{0\}$. Suppose that $\{s_1,...,s_k \}$ is a basis for $S$, $\{t_1,...,t_k \}$ is a basis for $T$, and $k+l = n$.
>
> Prove that $\{s_1,...,s_k,t_1,...,t_l \}$ is a basis for $V$.

My proof :

Suppose that $\alpha_1 s_1 +...+ \alpha_k s_k + \alpha_{k+1}t_1 +...+ \alpha_{n}t_l = 0$ for some $\{ \alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{n} \subset F$

Then $\alpha_{k+1}t_1 + ... + \alpha_{n} t_l = -(\alpha_1 s_1 + ... + \alpha_k s_k) \in \text{span} \{ s_1,...,s_k  \}= S$.

Also, $\alpha_{k+1}t_1 + ... + \alpha_{n} t_l \in \text{span} \{ t_1,...,t_l  \}   = T $.

By [Exercise 2.5.15](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583902/the-union-of-two-linearly-independent-subsets?noredirect=1#comment5333618_2583902), $\{s_1,...,s_k,t_1,...,t_l \}$ is a linearly independent set with $n$ vectors.

Since $\text{dim}(V)=n$, any set of $n+1$ vectors is linearly dependent.

If there exists $v \notin \text{span} \{s_1,...,s_k,t_1,...,t_l \} $, then we could add that vector $v$ to the set to obtain a set of $n+1$ linearly independent vectors.

However, since $\text{dim}(V)=n$, any set of $n+1$ vectors is linearly dependent.

This shows that every $v \in V$ belongs to $\text{span} \{s_1,...,s_k,t_1,...,t_l \} $.

Therefore, $\text{span} \{s_1,...,s_k,t_1,...,t_l \} = V$ and is therefore a basis for $V$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\{t_1,\ldots,t_l\}$ instead of $\{t_1,\ldots,t_k\}$ in the question?

Comment: @yh016 Yes, that is typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the vectors are in bases of different subspaces, they are non-zero and linearly independent.  Therefore, their union is also a basis for the span of the new set.